Angular ssr not rendering in production
I have created a Angular app with @angular/ssr in v-17. It works fine in localhost but when deployed to production it is not rendering from server. It's rendering in network tab but is not showing  ng-server-context="ssr" in the app-root of production build.
So what we are doing is we are employing a Jenkins server to build the ssr files then copy the browser folder contents to /var/www/html then in the Jenkins workspace itself we run the server's main.js using sudo pm2 start main.js --name "frontend-server" --env production.
And it gets started when checked in pm2 logs, and after the Jenkins build is successful we are able to see the server passing doc in network tab but when checked in page source there is no ng-server-context="ssr" in the app-root of production build.  And we haven't configured a proxy for server side rendering in Apache2.
My server.ts
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import  express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';
import { join } from 'node:path';
import AppServerModule from './src/main.server';

//The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), '/dist/kaamresume/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')
    : join(distFolder, 'index.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req:any, res:any, next:any) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: distFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export default AppServerModule;

My server.main.ts:
export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server';

My app.module.server.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering, ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers:[provideServerRendering()]
})
export class AppServerModule {}

My app.module.ts:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ContainerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule, 
    MatInputModule,
    QuillModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot('pk_test_51OODACSIlX5eKJquLWNoSPyZvKHBwoL6J5Cg4v7w6bNCBWofCiAZeFOHIWpqsnHPnRrkKWzZbNEQjiUH3h1Mg10000KYFkmFhP'),
    MatSnackBarModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      // useClass: InterceptorService,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true
  },
  
    {

      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,

      useClass: RouteReuseService

    },
    DatePipe,
    provideClientHydration(),
   
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

My main.ts:
/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

import 'zone.js';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'; 
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

My tsconfig.server.json:
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@angular/localize"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}

My tsconfig.app.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "@angular/localize",
      "jquery"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    // "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    // "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}


What I can guess is happening is that you're querying Apache's web server. And Apache is serving /var/www/html where browser files live. However, in order to get SSR, you need to run the Node.js/Express server (which seems you're already doing via PM2). Then, that process should be the one handling network traffic, not Apache (or Apache forwarding traffic to that server process). Anyway, the one receiving traffic should be the server process if you want to get SSR. What it looks like is that Apache is serving the browser files, but you need the server process to do so in order to get SSR.
